# React: Screen reader can't read img alt text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

In my react js project I want the screen reader to read my img alt text when the user presses tab button. Screen reader can read the button next to the image, but not the image iself.

My Image component:
[image]

```
<Image {...image} alt="Hello world" />
```

**Image.js**

```
const ImageView = styled(({ objectFit, ...rest }) => <img loading="lazy" {...rest} />)(
  ({
    ...rest
  }) => {
    const { objectFit } = rest;
    return {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      objectFit: objectFit,
    };
  },
);

export const Image = (props) => (
  <ImageView {...props} />
);
```

When I use `tabIndex={1}`, the Screen reader can access and read the alt text. But I need to make the screen reader access my image alt text without using `tabIndex`.

**Any Help?**

Comment: I have multiple components on the same page so the screen reader is not reading if I put one component on a separate page its works.

Comment: Sounds like it's working correctly.  An `<img>` is not keyboard focusable by default with the TAB key but a screen reader user can use the 'i' key to navigate to an image and hear the alt text.  If the image is not an interactive element, that is, if nothing happens when you click on it, then you should **not** give it a `tabindex`.